# Intuitive reason that connected spaces force discrete valued maps to be constant.

Tags: general-topology, connectedness

Precursor definitions and proposition, from Bredon's Topology and Geometry.

**Definition:** Let $X$ be a topological space. A **separation** of $X$ is a pair $U,V$ of disjoint, nonempty, open subsets of $X$ whose union is $X$. We say that $X$ is **disconnected** if such a separation exists, and say it is **connected** otherwise.

**Definition:**     Let $X$ be a space. A discrete valued map is a continuous function $f:X \rightarrow D$ where $D$ is a discrete space, i.e a topological space with the discrete topology.

*Proposition:*  A space $X$ is connected if and only if every discrete valued map $f:X \rightarrow D$ is constant.

> *Proof:*   It suffices to show that $X$ is disconnected if and only if there exists a discrete map $f:X \rightarrow D$ which is not constant. Suppose $A,B \subseteq X$ constitute a separation of $X$. Define a map $f:X \rightarrow \{0,1\}_{\text{disc}}$ by
> $$
>  f(x) = 
>  \begin{cases}
>   1 & \text{ if } x \in A \\
>   0 & \text{ if } x \in B
>  \end{cases}
>  $$
> Then $f$ is continuous; one readily checks $f^{-1}[\varnothing] = \varnothing, f^{-1}[\{0,1\}] = X, f^{-1}[0] = B, f^{-1}[1] = A$, all of which are open in $X$. It is clear that $f$ is not constant, take any $a \in A$ and $b \in B$, which are guaranteed to be distinct since $A \cap B = \varnothing$, then $f(a) = 1$ while $f(b) = 0$. Therefore $f$ is a discrete valued map which is non-constant. Suppose that $f:X \rightarrow Y$ is a discrete valued map which is not constant, and let $x,y\in X$ be two distinct points of $X$ for which $f(x) \neq f(y) \in D$. Since $D$ is a discrete space, singletons are open so that $f^{-1}[f(x)]$ is open in $X$. Remark that $D-\{f(x)\}$ is a subset of $D$, and as such is open in $D$, therefore $f^{-1}[D-\{f(x)\}] = X-f^{-1}[f(x)]$ is open in $X$. This means that $f^{-1}[f(x)]$ is a clopen set of $X$. It is clearly not-empty, and moreover since $y$ is a point distinct from $x$ not mapping to $f(x)$, it is also not all of $X$. Therefore $X$ is disconnected.

I can see that the proof of this statement works, but I don't see morally why one would ever come up with this connection in the first place. What is the intuitive reason that a connected space forces discrete maps out of it to be constant, beyond the fact that if one wasn't you could create a separation of $X$? Please let me know if I can be more clear, and thank you in advance.

Comment: @IrvingRabin Sure.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If $X$ is connected and $f$ on $X$ is continuous, then the image of $f$ is connected. A connected discrete space cannot have more than one point.

Answer (score 1):

*Intuitive Reason:* I like to imagine this in the sense of "paths." Define $I := [0,1]$ for simplicity. A path in $X$ is a continuous map $\phi: I \to X$.

Let $\phi$ be a path in $X$, and suppose $f: X \to D$ is a continuous map into a discrete space $D$. As $D$ is discrete, each point in $D$ is isolated. Now, one can consider the *"image"* of the path $\phi$ in the discrete space $D$ via the map $f$, namely the composition $f\circ \phi: I \to D$. If the map $f$ were not constant on $X$, one could come up with a suitable path $\phi$ in $X$ such that its *"image"* in $X$ consisted of more than one point. This is contrary to intuition - since it is very reasonable to expect the image of a path in a connected space (which is defined by a continuous function $\phi: I \to X$) to not have *"discrete jumps."*

---

*Edit:* As pointed out in the comments, not all connected spaces are path-connected, but this is just to build intuition, hence the handwaving.

Comment: It should be noted that not all connected spaces are path-connected.

Comment: @QiyuWen Yeah, certainly! This is just for intuition, hence a little handwavy.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose you have a continuous function $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow D$ where $D$ is discrete.  Suppose $f$ was not constant; at some point $x\in \mathbb{R}$, the function changes.  What is the smallest amount it could change?  Answer: the smallest distance between consecutive points in $D$.  But then, $f$ would not be continuous at $x$, and we know that $f$ is continuous.  Therefore, $f$ must be constant.

Answer (score 1):

Intuitively, I look at what happens if f$X\subset R$ and use the use the absolute value as a metric. I  associate the discrete topology with the discrete metric, so all unequal elements are the same distance apart from each other.

Continuity of $f:X\to D $ means $\forall \epsilon>0, \exists \delta>0 $ so $d_X(x_1,x_2)<\delta \implies d_D(y_1,y_2)<\epsilon$

But in the discrete metric, $\exists \epsilon_2>0, \forall y_1,y_2 \in D, y_1\ne y_2,  d_D(y_1,y_2)>\epsilon_2$.

By definition of a continuous function from X to D, a continuous mapping to the Discrete space requires the function be constant.

So the question is  if this holds for a general topological space as the domain.

In this context, a function is continuous iff every pre-image of an open set in the range is an open set in the domain.

For any element  $y \in  D$, its complement $(y^c)$ (abusing notation to represent all elements of the range not equal to) $y$.  That set is open and singletons are open in the discrete space. The function maps the domain to the range, so  $f^{-1}(y) \cup  f^{-1}(y^c)=X$. By definition of a function the sets are disjoint, (vertical line test). By definition of a continuous function, both preimages are open. All elements are either mapped to $y$ or its complement, so the union of the preimages is the whole domain.

$f^{-1}(y)$ can't be empty by hypothesis. If $f^{-1}(y^c)$ is empty, we have a constant function.

Suppose $f^{-1}(y^c) $ is non-empty. Then by definition we have a separation.

So $f$ is contant or can be used to create a separation.

Answer (score -1):

Note first that for any function $f: X \to Y$, $X$ is a disjoint union of the preimages of the points of $Y$. If $Y$ is discrete, these points are open so $f$ being continuous implies that those preimages are open, thus giving a separation of $X$ unless all but one preimage is empty.